# Google Sign In SDK 2.4.0 Archive Linker Error

Tags: objective-c, linker, google-signin

I have added Google Sign In SDK 2.4.0, when i build my app i am successfully login to google  but at time of archive the linker error has occur as shown below:

"duplicate symbol l012 in:

```
  /GooglePFrameWork/GoogleSignIn.framework/GoogleSignIn(NSString+GIDAdditions.o)
  /GooglePFrameWork/GoogleSignIn.framework/GoogleSignIn(GTMUIImage+Resize.o)
```

duplicate symbol l013 in:

```
/FrameWorks/Fabric.framework/Fabric(FABIcon.o)
/GooglePFrameWork/GoogleSignIn.framework/GoogleSignIn(GTMUIImage+Resize.o)
```

ld: 198 duplicate symbols for architecture arm64

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

can anyone please help me to solve this issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by upgrade Xcode from Xcode6 to Xcode7.

Below is copied from CHANGELOG.md, from v2.3.0 it required Xcode7 but canceled after v2.3.2, maybe there's still something wrong.

> ## 2015-10-26 -- v2.4.0
>
> - Updates sign-in button with the new Google logo.
> - Supports domain restriction for sign-in.
> - Allows refreshing ID tokens.
>
> ## 2015-10-09 -- v2.3.2
>
> - No longer requires Xcode 7.
>
> ## 2015-10-01 -- v2.3.1
>
> - Fixes a crash in |GIDProfileData|'s |imageURLWithDimension:|.
>
> ## 2015-09-25 -- v2.3.0
>
> - Requires Xcode 7.0 or above.
> - Uses SFSafariViewController for signing in on iOS 9.  |uiDelegate| must be
>     set for this to work.
> - Optimizes fetching user profile.
> - Supports GTMFetcherAuthorizationProtocol in GIDAuthentication.